# TestNG error null point exception error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Hi I am receiving following error can someone help me out with debugging below code,

package testngpackg;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ARXNewTest {

     ChromeDriver driver;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void set()   {
    //ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    //FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
//  testprofile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    //testprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium Web Driver 3.0.1\\geckodriver-v0.12.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     String baseURL = "<URL>";
    driver.get(baseURL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

  @Test
  public void OpenBrowser() {
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In")).click();
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        driver.findElement(By.id("tx_username")).sendKeys("my email id");


  }


  }
```

Error

FAILED: OpenBrowser

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testngpackg.ARXNewTest.OpenBrowser(ARXNewTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)
```

I am getting null point error while execution of above code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You find a NullPointerException cause driver is not getting initialized before that point. You tried to initialize a WebDriver instance inside beforeMethod() method, but it was local.

Use following code :

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Instead

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your Question-

A few words about the Solution:

1. Avoid creating unnecessary instances. You have `ChromeDriver driver;` but not used it anywhere.
2. Keep your methods & code-blocks separated so that you can identify them properly.
3. Remove the unwanted code when you are asking for help `//ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();`
4. In `System.setProperty` you have mentioned the `Key` as `webdriver.chrome.driver` but you have provided the `value` as `C:\\Selenium Web Driver 3.0.1\\geckodriver-v0.12.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe`
5. Keep you code properly formatted so that it is easier to understand code-blocks.
6. Manage the opening & closing of `{` & `}` so you don't run into unexpected results.
7. Provide names to the methods as per the functiosn achieved through the code within. Your `OpenBrowser()` method have nothing to do with Browser opening.
8. Here is the working set of your own code with some minimal tweaks:

   ```
   public class Q43910679_null_pointer 
   {

       @BeforeMethod
       public void set()   
       {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
           String baseURL = "https://gmail.com";
           driver.get(baseURL);
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       }

       @Test
       public void OpenBrowser() 
       {
           System.out.println("Open Browser Method");
       }

   }
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.